# What is the difference between useGetQuery() and useLazyGetQuery() in redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux

What is the difference between **useGetQuery()** and **useLazyGetQuery()** in **redux toolkit** and when to use them?

Comment: these hooks are part of the `RTK query `package.
`redux toolkit` just includes this package by default.

Answer (score 0):

[According to The Docs:](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery)

### useLazyQuery

> A React hook similar to `useQuery`, but with manual control over when
> the data fetching occurs.

#### usage

```
const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] =
  api.endpoints.getPosts.useLazyQuery(options)
// or
const [trigger, result, lastPromiseInfo] = api.useLazyGetPostsQuery(options)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **useQuery** hook is used when you want to fetch data on screen load. For example fetch userprofile on profile screen.

But **useLazyquery** is used when you want to control over the api calling, like on button click.